# Vagrant dumping physical memory of a VBox

Tags: vagrant, virtualization, vagrantfile

I want to take a dump of the entirety of the physical memory of a virtual machine running on VBox on vagrant. I was wondering if vagrant can do that for me? It seems like the vagrant commands are pretty limited. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it inside of VM:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/fmem of=/tmp/fmem_dump.dd bs=1MB count=10
```

If you want to dump the memory of one process you can use:

```
$ cat /proc/[pid]/maps
```

Comment: Good answer! Didn't know about /dev/fmen (just about /dev/mem, which is not accessible).. You should mention, that the `fmem` kernel module needs to be installed in order to make this work

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to script this though. I want to suspend all the VMs running and dump the physical memory at the same time. The virsh library can do that so I was wondering if vagrant has the same functionality